# How to disable “Unresponsive page” warning in Chromium?

Tags: javascript, chromium

I’m using Chrome on Linux to develop a GWT application, and every time I’m stepping through the debugger Chrome complains that the page is unresponsive (which is normal). It’s getting very annoying.

I looked through pages of command line switches and found nothing, is it really impossible to disable that damn warning?

Answer (score 2):

The time out issue has been [filed as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=76230&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&id=76230). You can add comments or simply "vote it up" to have the issue resolved. The more of us who comment and vote, the greater the chance they will actually do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try --disable-hang-monitor, that should work.

Comment: Some explanation on why? Other possiblities to try?